# Need to print the column or a row contains my predicted label

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using Decision Tree algorithm to predict the label from a test file. However, I need to print the complete row or a single cell which consist that label. The code which I am working on is mentioned below.

```
import numpy as np
import csv
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score,confusion_matrix
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn import tree


path = "train_names.csv"
file=open(path)
reader = csv.reader(file)
data = np.asarray(list(reader))  
#train data
names_train=data[1:,[0,1,2,3,4]]
label_train=data[1:,[5]]

#test data
names_test=data1[1:,[0,1,2,3,4]]
label_test=data1[1:,[5]]

decisionTreeClassifier = DecisionTreeClassifier()
decisionTreeClassifier.fit(names_train,label_train)
predictions = decisionTreeClassifier.predict(names_test)
print("Accuracy: ",accuracy_score(label_test,predictions))

for i in range(0,len(names_test)):
  print (predictions[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to say that you want to print the output of your predictions? If so you can simply just call `print(predictions)` or you can use `sklearn`'s `confusion_matrix` by importing this

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(label_test, predictions)
print(cm)
# your X-axis is the predicted while Y-axis is the truth
```

You can also print the model's score by using this

```
decisionTreeClassifier.score(names_test, label_test)
```

Comment: i already printed out the predictions. I need to print the other columns which contains my predicted label. for instance my csv file contains 

1 2 3 4 normal
5 6 7 8 abnormal

The predicted output is normal as per ML algorithm. My question is, how could print "1 2 3 4" ?

Comment: I dont quite get your question. Maybe it helps if you edit your question with a small segment of your data, so that we can get a better sensing of what we are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

Just you have to iteration both the input values(`names_test`) and the predicted outputs (`predictions`). Try this!

```
predictions = decisionTreeClassifier.predict(names_test)

for x,y_pred in zip(names_test, predictions):
    print(x,y_pred)
```